# Network flow problem to minimize differences between nodes

Tags: network-flow

What type of algorithm should I be researching to solve the following problem?

Each node has a potential that is a function (linear or non linear) of the net flow in/out of that node.

Nodes are connected by a directed graph.

The objective is to minimize the differential across all nodes.

As a new comer to OR I feel this should be a common problem but have struggled to find an example in the literature. It feels somewhere close to a min cost problem, but there is no cost applied on the flows along the arcs.

Comment: If the function for node $i\in N$ is $f_i$, do you want to minimize the sum of differences $\sum_{i\in N, j\in N} |f_i-f_j|$ or maybe minimize the max of differences $\max_{i\in N, j\in N} |f_i-f_j|$?

Comment: would be to minimise the sum of the differences

Comment: We are missing some key details about your problem.  What properties does your flow have to satisfy? I assume you do not require flow-in = flow-out at each node, since the potential is a function of flow-in - flow-out. What requires there to be any flow at all?

Comment: You may use $\min \sum_i \vert f_i \vert$

Comment: Thanks @SutanuMajumdar, I think this moving me in the right direction. In which case would this be a more straight forward linear programming problem?

Comment: @NaturalLogZ, an example of the type of network I was imagining might be heat transfer between rooms in a house, where each node is a room, which lose heat at different rates and may have their own heating source.

Comment: @granddejeuner, yes it would be a non-linear program or linear (absolute terms in the objective can be linearized if you want, otherwise most solvers can handle absolute terms).